# Different number of threads, different answers

Tags: c++, c, windows, cuda, neural-network

So I have some neural network simulator code that works correctly on the CPU, and the parallel version agrees with the serial version to at least 6 decimal places with a 32-thread single block on both of my CUDA under Win7 PCs, but with 1 block and 64 threads slightly different values for Wt are generated. Wt values are often no more than 3 decimal places in agreement, and when I attempt to eliminate race conditions by embedding __syncthreads() within the loops, the Wt values appear as Not A Number when copied back to the CPU.

Can someone give me a hint what I might be doing wrong? I've included the parallelized code below, and knlBackProp is being called with lSampleQtyReq=10000, o=1, and Option='R':

```
// device-global variables to facilitate data transfer
__device__ __constant__ __align__(8) struct rohanContext devSes;
__device__ __constant__ struct rohanLearningSet devLearn;
__device__ __align__(16) struct rohanNetwork devNet;

__device__ double devdReturn[1024*1024];
__device__ double devdRMSE=0;
__device__ int devlReturn[1024*1024];
__device__ int devlTrainable=0;

extern"C"
int knlBackProp(struct rohanContext& rSes, long lSampleQtyReq, long o, char Option)
{mIDfunc /*! divides error in yielded values and back-propagates corrections among weights */
// Option S - single sample correction only
// Option E - keep existing weights, count trainable samples only
// Option R - perform corrections for all trainable samples
    int lTotal=0;

    cudaMemcpyToSymbol( "devlTrainable", &lTotal, sizeof(int) ); // init return value on both sides
        mCheckCudaWorked
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate( &start);
    cudaEventCreate( &stop);

            cudaEventRecord( start, 0);
        mtkBackPropMT<<< rSes.iBpropBlocks , rSes.iBpropThreads >>>( lSampleQtyReq, o, Option);
            cudaEventRecord( stop, 0);
            mCheckCudaWorked

    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol( &lTotal, "devlTrainable", sizeof(long) ); // retrieve return value
        mCheckCudaWorked
    cudaEventSynchronize( stop);
        float elapsedTime;
        cudaEventElapsedTime( &elapsedTime, start, stop);
    conPrintf("DEVICE: Time to complete BackProp kernel: %3.1f ms\n", elapsedTime);
        cudaEventDestroy( start);
        cudaEventDestroy( stop);

    return lTotal;
}


__global__ __device__ void mtkBackPropMT( long lSampleQtyReq, long o, char Option)
{/*! divides error in yielded values and back-propagates corrections among weights */
// Option S - single sample correction only
// Option E - keep existing weights, count trainable samples only
// Option R - perform corrections for all trainable samples

    if(Option=='E' || Option=='e'){ //
        devlTrainable=0; // reset global mem trainable counter
        subkBackPropEoptMT(lSampleQtyReq, o);
    }

    if(Option=='S' || Option=='s'){
        devlTrainable=0; // reset global mem trainable counter
        subkBackPropSoptMT(lSampleQtyReq, false,  devNet, devNet.Signals, devNet.Zs, devNet.Wt, devNet.Deltas, devLearn.gpuXInputs, devLearn.gpuYEval, devLearn.gpudYEval);
    }

    if(Option=='R' || Option=='r'){ //
        devlTrainable=0; // reset global mem trainable counter
        subkBackPropRoptMT(lSampleQtyReq, o);
    }
}


__device__ void subkBackPropRoptMT(long lSampleQtyReq, long o)
{/*! flags and counts samples meeting  */
    long OUTROWLEN=devLearn.iOutputQty+1; // prepare array index and width
    //long tIx = threadIdx.x + devSes.iEvalThreads * blockIdx.x; // tIx is thread index over the kernel
    long tIx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x; // tIx is thread index over the kernel
    //long lTotalThreads = devSes.iBpropThreads * devSes.iBpropBlocks; // total number of threads
    double maxSquared = devSes.dMAX * devSes.dMAX ; //needed to compart to stored delta squared values

    devlTrainable=0; // clear global mem accumulator; out of bound samples will remain at this value
    for (long s=0; s<lSampleQtyReq; ++s){ // iterate over samples
        if( devLearn.gpudSE1024[IDX2C( o, s, OUTROWLEN )] > maxSquared ){ // if the MAX criterion is exceeded   
            if(tIx==0)++devlTrainable; // increment the counter
            subkBackPropSoptMT( s, true, devNet, devNet.Signals, devNet.Zs, devNet.Wt, devNet.Deltas, devLearn.gpuXInputs, devLearn.gpuYEval, devLearn.gpudYEval);
        }
    }
} 


__device__ void subkBackPropSoptMT(long s, int o, rohanNetwork& Net, cuDoubleComplex * Signals, cuDoubleComplex * Zs, cuDoubleComplex * Wt, cuDoubleComplex * Deltas, cuDoubleComplex * XInputs, cuDoubleComplex * YEval, double * dYEval )
{/*! propagates adjustment of weights backwards preceeding layers from the chosen network output. */
    // s is sample's index
    // o is an optional method selection parameter; print/don't print as of 2/29/12
    long index, kindex; // for warpwise loops
    long tIx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x; // tIx is thread index over the kernel
    long lTotalThreads = gridDim.x * blockDim.x; // total number of threads
    const cuDoubleComplex cdcZero = { 0, 0 };

    /* clear all temp values BP0 */
    for (long offset=0; (index =offset+tIx)< MAXNEURONS ; offset+=lTotalThreads){ // index stands for i
        Deltas[index]=cdcZero;
        Signals[index]=cdcZero;
        Zs[index]=cdcZero;
    }
    /* re-evaluate sample to load temp values. BPI */
    subkEvalSampleBetaMT( devSes, s, Net, (s==0), Signals, Zs, Wt, XInputs, YEval, dYEval);
    /* begin error calculation. BPII */
    cuDoubleComplex Deltastar /* measured error at the chosen network output. */ ;
    /* calc top layer deltas. */
    long TOP=Net.iLayerQty-1;
    int ROWLEN=Net.iNeuronQTY[TOP];
    //for(int i=0; i<Net.iNeuronQTY[TOP]; ++i){
    for (long offset=0; (index =offset+tIx)< Net.iNeuronQTY[TOP] ; offset+=lTotalThreads){ // index stands for i
         // delta-star = D - Y = Desired output minus actual output from evaluation
         // D is the cplx coords of the sector of the desired answer        Y is the complex result of evaluation of the given sample, unactivated. */
        Deltastar = CxSubtractCxUT( 
                        devLearn.gpuDOutputs[ IDX2C( index, s, ROWLEN ) ], 
                        Signals[Net.iNeuronOfst[TOP]+index] );
         /* divide the correction; delta = alpha * delta-star / n+1 (but alpha is always 1 for now). */
        //Deltas[Net.iNeuronOfst[TOP]+index] = CxDivideRlUT( Deltastar, Net.iDendrtQTY[TOP] );
        Deltas[Net.iNeuronOfst[TOP]+index] = CxMultiplyRlUT( Deltastar, Net.dINV_S[TOP] );
    }
    __syncthreads();
    /* Now distribute the correction to lower layers if any. BPII.1 */
    if (Net.iLayerQty>2){  /* remember layer 0 = inputs, layer 1 = bottom row, layer {2..iLayerQty-2} = middle row, layer iLayerQty-1 = top row. */
        for (int L=Net.iLayerQty-1; L>1; --L){
            long LAY = L; /* setup access to layers. */
            long TRIB = L-1; /* trib for tributary.*/
            int iTributQTY=Net.iNeuronQTY[TRIB];
            //int Sj=Net.iDendrtQTY[TRIB]; if (TRIB==1) Sj=1; // Sj=1 for firest hidden layer
            for (int i=1; i<Net.iNeuronQTY[LAY]; ++i) { // skip 0th neuron as its weights are either 1 (div identity) or 0 (div forbidden) and don't change anyway
                // k index must begin at 1, neuron zero not valid for correction
                //for (int k=1; k<iTributQTY; ++k) { /* the contribution to ith neuron's kth tributary's delta = i's delta/i's weight k. */
                for (long offset=1; ( kindex =offset+tIx)< iTributQTY ; offset+=lTotalThreads){ // kindex stands for k
                                  Deltas[Net.iNeuronOfst[TRIB]+kindex] 
                    = CxAddCxUT ( Deltas[Net.iNeuronOfst[TRIB]+kindex] , 
                        CxDivideCxUT( 
                            Deltas[Net.iNeuronOfst[LAY]+i] , 
                            Wt[IDX2C( Net.iWeightOfst[LAY]+kindex, i, iTributQTY )] ));
                }
            }
            for (long offset=1; ( kindex =offset+tIx)< iTributQTY ; offset+=lTotalThreads){ // kindex stands for k
                //cuDoubleComplex preDiv=Deltas[Net.iNeuronOfst[TRIB]+kindex]; // diagnostic purpose only, remove if removing other diags
                //Deltas[Net.iNeuronOfst[TRIB]+kindex] 
                //  = CxDivideRlUT( 
                //      Deltas[Net.iNeuronOfst[TRIB]+kindex] , 
                //      Sj );
                Deltas[Net.iNeuronOfst[TRIB]+kindex] 
                    = CxMultiplyRlUT( 
                        Deltas[Net.iNeuronOfst[TRIB]+kindex] , 
                        Net.dINV_S[TRIB] );
            }
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();
    /* error distribution completed */
    /* and now update the weights BP III */
    /* adj weights on first hidden layer. */
        int FHID = 1;
        int SIG = 0;
        int iSignalQTY=Net.iNeuronQTY[SIG]; //rSes.rLearn->iInputQty+1;
        int iHidWidth=Net.iNeuronQTY[FHID];
    for (int k=1; k<iHidWidth; ++k){
        //for (int i=0; i<iSignalQTY; ++i){  
        for (long offset=0; ( index =offset+tIx)< iSignalQTY ; offset+=lTotalThreads){ // index stands for i
            /* dW=d*xbar/s1/|z|= neuron's delta * input's conjugate / ( dendrites+1 * abs of input i ). */
                        Wt[IDX2C( Net.iWeightOfst[FHID]+index, k, iSignalQTY )]
            =CxAddCxUT( Wt[IDX2C( Net.iWeightOfst[FHID]+index, k, iSignalQTY )] , 
                CxDivideRlUT( 
                    CxMultiplyCxUT( 
                        Deltas[Net.iNeuronOfst[FHID]+k] , 
                        CxConjugateUT( Signals[Net.iNeuronOfst[SIG]+index] ) 
                    ) , 
                    CxAbsUT( Zs[Net.iNeuronOfst[FHID]+k] ) // N+1 denominator factor is considered redundant - JAW & IA 2/27/12
                )
            );
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();
    /* re-evaluate sample to update temp values. */
    subkEvalSampleBetaMT( devSes, s, Net, false, Signals, Zs, Wt, XInputs, YEval, dYEval);
    if (Net.iLayerQty>2){
         /* now use those outputs' conjugates and the deltas to adjust middle layers. BP III.1 */
        for (int L=2; L<Net.iLayerQty-1; ++L){
             /* setup access to layers. */
            long LAY = L;
            long TRIB = L-1;
            //int iLayWidth=Net.iNeuronQTY[LAY];
            int iTribWidth=Net.iNeuronQTY[TRIB];
            for (int k=1; k<Net.iNeuronQTY[LAY]; ++k){
                //for (int i=0; i<Net.iNeuronQTY[TRIB]; ++i){  
                for (long offset=0; ( index =offset+tIx)< Net.iNeuronQTY[TRIB] ; offset+=lTotalThreads){ // index stands for i
                    /* the adjustment added to kth neuron's ith trib's weight = k's delta * complex conjugate of i's signal / (abs of k's previous-wt product-sum * dendrites+1)  . */
                                Wt[IDX2C( Net.iWeightOfst[LAY]+index, k, iTribWidth )]
                    =CxAddCxUT( Wt[IDX2C( Net.iWeightOfst[LAY]+index, k, iTribWidth )] , 
                        CxDivideRlUT( 
                            CxMultiplyCxUT( 
                                Deltas[Net.iNeuronOfst[LAY]+k] , 
                                CxConjugateUT( Signals[Net.iNeuronOfst[TRIB]+index] ) 
                            ) ,
                            ( 
                                CxAbsUT( Zs[Net.iNeuronOfst[LAY]+k] ) // N+1 denominator factor is considered redundant - JAW & IA 2/27/12
                            )
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
            /* layer is complete. */
            subkEvalSampleBetaMT( devSes, s, Net, true, Signals, Zs, Wt, XInputs, YEval, dYEval);
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();

    /* correct output layer BP III.3 */
    long SUB = TOP-1; 
    //int iTopWidth=Net.iNeuronQTY[TOP];
    int iSubWidth=Net.iNeuronQTY[SUB];

    for (int k=1; k<Net.iNeuronQTY[TOP]; ++k){
        //for (int i=0; i<Net.iNeuronQTY[SUB]; ++i){  
        for (long offset=0; ( index =offset+tIx)< Net.iNeuronQTY[SUB] ; offset+=lTotalThreads){ // index stands for i
            /* For last layer only, adjustment to kth neuron's ith weight = k's delta * complex conjugate of i's signal / ( dendrites+1)  . */
                        Wt[IDX2C( Net.iWeightOfst[TOP]+index, k, iSubWidth )]
            =CxAddCxUT( Wt[IDX2C( Net.iWeightOfst[TOP]+index, k, iSubWidth )] , 
                CxMultiplyCxUT( 
                    Deltas[Net.iNeuronOfst[TOP]+k] , 
                    CxConjugateUT( Signals[Net.iNeuronOfst[SUB]+index] ) 
                )
            );  // N+1 denominator factor is considered redundant - JAW & IA 2/27/12
        }
    }
    /* backprop is complete. */
}


__device__ void subkEvalSampleBetaMT(rohanContext& Ses, long s, rohanNetwork& Net, int o, cuDoubleComplex * Signals, cuDoubleComplex * Zs, cuDoubleComplex * Wt, cuDoubleComplex * XInputs, cuDoubleComplex * YEval, double * dYEval )
{// Beta uses fixed length fields instead of nested pointer layers
    // delta squared is not updated, since they'll be updated when RMSE is checked at the end of a pass through the learning set
    long index, kindex; // for warpwise loops
    long tIx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x; // tIx is thread index over the kernel
    long lTotalThreads = gridDim.x * blockDim.x; // total number of threads
    const cuDoubleComplex cdcZero = { 0, 0 };
     /*! layer zero (inputs) is special. */
    long INROWLEN=Net.iNeuronQTY[0];//rSes.rLearn->iInputQty+1;
    //for (int i=0; i<INROWLEN; ++i){
    for (long offset=0; (index =offset+tIx)< INROWLEN ; offset+=lTotalThreads){ // index stands for i
        Signals[Net.iNeuronOfst[0]+index]= XInputs[IDX2C( index, s, INROWLEN )];
    }
     /*! middle and top layers. */
    for (int L=1; L<Net.iLayerQty; ++L){
        //struct rohanLayer& lay = Net.rLayer[L];
        long LAY=L;
        int TRIB=L-1; // index of previous layer
        int iNeuronQTY=Net.iNeuronQTY[LAY];
        int iSignalQTY=Net.iDendrtQTY[LAY]; // signal qty depends on size of previous layer
        //for (int k=0; k<iNeuronQTY; ++k){ //Neuron zero is not skipped, its output should be 1+0i as a check
        for (long offset=0; (kindex =offset+tIx)< iNeuronQTY ; offset+=lTotalThreads){ // kindex stands for k
            Zs[Net.iNeuronOfst[LAY]+kindex]=cdcZero;
            for (int i=0; i<iSignalQTY; ++i){ //walk weights on inputs from previous layer
                           Zs[Net.iNeuronOfst[LAY]+kindex] = 
                CxAddCxUT( Zs[Net.iNeuronOfst[LAY]+kindex] , 
                    CxMultiplyCxUT(
                        Wt[IDX2C( Net.iWeightOfst[LAY] + i, kindex, iSignalQTY )],
                        Signals[Net.iNeuronOfst[TRIB]+i] ) ) ;
            }
            // ACTIVATE //
            Signals[Net.iNeuronOfst[LAY]+kindex] = CxActivateUT( Zs[Net.iNeuronOfst[LAY]+kindex]);
        }
    }
    /*! last layer values are converted and stored here */
    long TOP = Net.iLayerQty-1;
    long OUTROWLEN=Net.iNeuronQTY[TOP];
    //for (int i=0; i<Net.iNeuronQTY[TOP]; ++i){ // continuous conversion begins here 
    for (long offset=0; (index =offset+tIx)< OUTROWLEN ; offset+=lTotalThreads){ // index stands for i
        YEval[IDX2C( index, s, OUTROWLEN )]= Signals[Net.iNeuronOfst[TOP]+index] ; // store final complex output(s)
        dYEval[IDX2C( index, s, OUTROWLEN )]=FUnitCxUT( YEval[IDX2C( index, s, OUTROWLEN )] ) * Net.iSectorQty; // convert final complex outputs to sectors and store that
        if(devLearn.iContOutputs==false) // round off decimal if disc activation is set
            dYEval[IDX2C( index, s, OUTROWLEN )]=int(dYEval[IDX2C( index, s, OUTROWLEN )]);
    }
     /*! end of sample evaluation. */
}

__device__ cuDoubleComplex CxActivateUT(const cuDoubleComplex Z)
{/// applies ContActivation or discrete activation function to cx neuron output and returns Phi(Z)
    /// This fn should be phased out in favor of a GPU device vector based fn
    cuDoubleComplex phi;
    if (devNet.bContActivation) { // apply ContActivation activation function to weighted sum : phi(z)=z/|z|
        phi = CxDivideRlUT( Z, CxAbsUT( Z ) );
    }
    else {  // apply Discrete activation function to weighted sum : s=int(arctan(z)*k/2pi), phi(z)=(X(s),Y(s))
        double theta = atan2(Z.y, Z.x); // theta = arctan y/x
        int iSector = (int)((theta * devNet.dK_DIV_TWO_PI) + devNet.iSectorQty) % devNet.iSectorQty;
        phi = devNet.gpuSectorBdry[iSector];
        //printf(" %f+%fi %d Activate\n", phi.x, phi.y, threadIdx.x);
    }
    return phi;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with cuda, but your posted code is over 300 lines. Ever hear of [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: You can't seriously expect someone to sit down and sift through 300+ lines of unintelligible, recursive code that can't actually be run to find what is probably a subtle memory race? If you can't make the effort to reduce the scope of the problem down to a compact repro case someone else could compile and run, why should you expect someone else would make the effort to answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not going to read all that code, but I can give you a strong hint.  The warp size is 32 threads, so the 64-thread case will run two warps/block -- in the former case you can't have any instruction pointer based race conditions, however, in the second case, you will effectively have two groups of threads with different IPs scheduled at different times.  You may already know much of this (hence the syncthreads), but the above really makes it almost certain that you simply have one more race condition you haven't accounted for yet.

Putting in the sync-threads is a good start to try and isolate it.  Are you sure that in your loops, the source data of one warp is not overwritten by the other warp?  If not try put in syncthreads into your inner loops just for debug purposes to see what may be causing the race condition.

Comment: While that is pretty sound advice, use of `__syncthreads()` inside loops requires some care. The execution model requires that every thread in a given warp executes the `bar.sync` instruction before the warp will continue. If there is branch divergence within the warp so that one or more threads branch around the `bar.sync` instruction, deadlock will result.

Comment: There are numerous source level debuggers available for CUDA. I recommend you single step the code and help narrow down the problem. As a point of style avoid using long. Its not portable.